# Access vhost via ip address on lan

Tags: php, wamp, vhosts

I am running WAMP and using CodeIgniter for my project and have this on my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@yahoo.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myproject/assets"
    ServerName myproject.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/myproject.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/myproject.dev-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now to access this, I added this line on `windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 myproject.dev
```

Now for the other computers on the network, I have to edit the `hosts` file of EACH computer so they can access my virtual host. (yes of course I have to use my ip address instead `127.0.0.1` for other computers)

Now my question is, is there a way that they can access my project by only using my ip address on the browser's address bar like this?

```
http://192.168.1.112/myproject
```

I mean there are 100 users that will access that project and it's a big hassle if I edit each one's hosts file. Like adding something to `.htaccess`,  or to the `routes` of CodeIgniter, or to the `<virtualHost>`

Note:
By the way, when we are still NOT using Codeigniter (plain PHP codes), this is not a problem. But because of Codeigniter's structure, we can't do it anymore.

Comment: Exactly like that. Just go to your WAMP icon in the system tray and click "Put Online" to allow it access from outside

Comment: It's already online. When I use the address `http://192.168.1.112/myproject` on the browser, it only show the files under the header `Index of /`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just add a DNS entry that points to your IP address and set that as the ServerName that apache responds to?

Alternatively you can do virtual hosting based on IP address and port as described here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html

In summary you should be able to do:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.112:8000>
  ServerAdmin admin@yahoo.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myproject/assets"
  ServerName myproject.dev
  ErrorLog "logs/myproject.dev-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/myproject.dev-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And have people access it via

```
http://192.168.1.112:8000/myproject
```

But, don't forget to add a Listen directive for port 8000 (or whatever you choose) if you use IP-based Virtual hosts

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Port listening did the trick. Now I'll consider doing this to all my projects. Like assigning each project to different ports.

Answer (score 0):

It might work of you create an alias called **/myproject** in wamp server and point the document root to 'C:/wamp/www/myproject/assets'

Make sure you have set your wamp server status to online by selecting 'Put Online' in wamp server system tray icon.

Comment: Virtual Hosts are a far better and more flexible solution and allow you to have multiple projects all served from one Apache. Its a bot like the hosting companies do when you buy a shared server